# What is the defiant "HMPH!" sound called?

Tags: terminology, parts-of-speech

What's the name of the sound a child makes after an angry, declarative and usually defiant statement.

**Parent:**

> John, you can't take a cookie out of the cookie jar.

**Child:**

> Yes, I can! ***HMPH***!

Comment: The grammatical term for such words that represent sounds is an 'onomatopoeia'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **humph** |həmf|
>
> exclamation
>
> used to express slightly scornful
>   doubt or dissatisfaction.
>
> ORIGIN natural utterance: first
>   recorded in English in the mid 16th
>   cent.

(Via Apple OS X Dictionary)

Comment: Another source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/humph

Comment: I wish I knew the answer, however, I think that it is an interjection and not really an exclamation...